# Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: whonix, dns

I keep getting dns errors when running scripts in the terminal.

Normal dns resolving in the tor browser (and chromium) works as it is supposed to though.

> ```
> user@host:~$ ping google.de
>
> ping: google.de: Temporary failure in name resolution
> ```

I'm running Manjaro as my main operating system and I use virtual-box for virtualization.

How can I fix this?

If you need any logs please comment below.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Whonix/comments/gr7es8/temporary_failure_in_name_resolution/

Comment: What does this have to do with Tor?

Comment: Ping uses UDP. See: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tor#UDP